# What's the best (easiest) way to convert ContentValues to a JSON string?

Tags: java, android

I need to convert ContentValues with variable items into a JSON string that I can save to a database and later use as the body of an HTTP request.  Everything on the net only converts in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need something turned into JSON in Android or Java you should use Googles GSON library. [Here is a link](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: no, you should use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) becuase is faster

Comment: I'm actually using GSON already, the trouble is when parsing a ContentValue object, my data is inside the mValues element, e.g. `{"mValues:"{"field1":"data","field2":"data2"}}`
How can I get just `{"field1":"data","field2":"data2"}` ?